# What's the correct term for "number of std deviations" away from a mean

Tags: statistics

I've computed the mean & variance of a set of values, and I want to pass along the value that represents the # of std deviations away from mean for each number in the set.  Is there a better term for this, or should I just call it num_of_std_devs_from_mean ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some suggestions here:
[Standard score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) (z-value, z-score, normal score)

but "sigma" or "stdev_distance" would probably be clearer

Answer (score 4):

The standard deviation is usually denoted with the letter σ (sigma). Personally, I think more people will understand what you mean if you do say number of standard deviations.

As for a variable name, as long as you comment the declaration you could shorten it to std_devs.

Answer (score 4):

[sigma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) is what you want, I think.

Answer (score 1):

That is normalizing your values.  You could just refer to it as the normalized value.  Maybe norm_val would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I've always heard it as number of standard deviations

Answer (score 0):

[Deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviation_(statistics)) may be what you're after. Deviation is the distance between a data point and the mean.